# Left Align UICollectionView Cell When it has one item in Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I am creating collection view with several size of labels. These labels all have the same height but their widths are changed dynamically.

This is the code of my collection view layout:

```
EstimatedItemSize = new CGSize(50f, 35f);

MinimumInteritemSpacing = 10f;

MinimumLineSpacing = 10f;

public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
{
var attributes = base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect);

        for (var i = 1; i < attributes.Length; ++i)
        {
            var currentLayoutAttributes = attributes[i];
            var previousLayoutAttributes = attributes[i - 1];
            var maximumSpacing = MinimumInteritemSpacing;
            var previousLayoutEndPoint = previousLayoutAttributes.Frame.Right;
            if (previousLayoutEndPoint + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.Frame.Size.Width >= CollectionViewContentSize.Width)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var frame = currentLayoutAttributes.Frame;
            frame.X = previousLayoutEndPoint + maximumSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.Frame = frame;
        }
        return attributes;
    }
```

My question is: When I have one item in my collection view it's displayed in the center, and `LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method will not be called. But I need to display it on the left side.

If I change `EstimatedItemSize = new CGSize(50f, 35f)` to `ItemSize = new CGSize(50f, 35f)` it displays correctly but then the width is not changed dynamically.

Comment: I have post an Answer. Or you can use some other third-party lib like this: https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some codes to change the position of the first cell, when you use the `EstimatedItemSize`, like this:

```
        public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
        {

            var attributes = base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect);


            //Add these lines to change the first cell's position of the collection view.
            var firstCellFrame = attributes[0].Frame;
            firstCellFrame.X = 0;
            attributes[0].Frame = firstCellFrame;


            for (var i = 1; i < attributes.Length; ++i)
            {
                var currentLayoutAttributes = attributes[i];
                var previousLayoutAttributes = attributes[i - 1];
                var maximumSpacing = MinimumInteritemSpacing;
                var previousLayoutEndPoint = previousLayoutAttributes.Frame.Right;
                if (previousLayoutEndPoint + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.Frame.Size.Width >= CollectionViewContentSize.Width)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var frame = currentLayoutAttributes.Frame;
                frame.X = previousLayoutEndPoint + maximumSpacing;
                currentLayoutAttributes.Frame = frame;
            }
            return attributes;
        }
```

It works fine like this:

[image]